# Load many gif to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am facing problem when I download `gif` images and add in to collection view.
`gif` images are download well, but when i try to scroll very very quickly it's crash

Please help. I have two solutions

```
    /*
    cellForGif.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:54.0/255.f green:56.0/255.f blue:67.0/255.f alpha:1.0]CGColor];
    cellForGif.layer.borderWidth = 0.7;
    FLAnimatedImage __block *gifImage = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        gifImage = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)indexPath.row] ofType:@"gif"]]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cellForGif.gifImage.animatedImage = gifImage;
            cellForGif.linkOnGif = [self.linksArrayOnGifs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           //gifImage = nil;
        });
    });
    return cellForGif;
     */
    cellForGif.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:54.0/255.f green:56.0/255.f blue:67.0/255.f alpha:1.0]CGColor];
    cellForGif.layer.borderWidth = 0.7;
    FLAnimatedImage *gifImage = nil;
        gifImage = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)indexPath.row] ofType:@"gif"]]];
            cellForGif.gifImage.animatedImage = gifImage;
            cellForGif.linkOnGif = [self.linksArrayOnGifs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            //gifImage = nil;

    return cellForGif;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your approach.

You have to load all images before going to set them in `UICollectionViewCell`.

Let's say create an `NSArray` contains all `gif` images. After images are loaded successfully then set them to the cell.

By observing straight from your code, I see that you load an image from the main bundle in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. So it is obvious that it will take some time very little (nano sec). But that is also considered large when there are a large amount of data in a cell.

And it is possible that line

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
```

will return `nil` when you scroll very very quickly.

Add a comment if it is still not clear.

**EDIT:**

Loading images in the background will not affect UI and scrolling will be smoother.

Also, put `try-catch` block in that method to check what you have missed.

```
    cellForGif.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:54.0/255.f green:56.0/255.f blue:67.0/255.f alpha:1.0]CGColor];
    cellForGif.layer.borderWidth = 0.7;

    @try {
        FLAnimatedImage __block *gifImage = nil;        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            gifImage = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)indexPath.row] ofType:@"gif"]]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                cellForGif.gifImage.animatedImage = gifImage;
                cellForGif.linkOnGif = [self.linksArrayOnGifs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                //gifImage = nil;
            });
        });
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception.debugDescription);
    }
```

Comment: I should in viewDidLoad create NSArray and push in it all my gifs and then take my gifs from this array (i shouldn't take it from main bundle)

Comment: Check this line `gifImage = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)indexPath.row] ofType:@"gif"]]];` it shows that you are fetching data from path.

Comment: Yes z have 84 gifs.
I should in viewDidLoad create NSArray and push in it all my gifs and then take my gifs from this array (i shouldn't take it from main bundle). But this array also will take memory. And when i first scroll it is not smooth. (Then it is ok) Please tell me maybe i should use cache?And i correct understand you?

Comment: You don't need to you cache, as these images are in main bundle. And you have large number of images. You can not load into array. So do this in backgorund thread, will solve your scrolling problem.

Comment: Please can you explain me where i should use background thread?
in viewDidLoad 
for (int i = 0; i <= 83; i++) {
FLAnimatedImage *gifImage = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i] ofType:@"gif"]]];
[self.gifsArray addObject:gifImage];}
and in cellForRowAtIndexpath
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
cellForGif.gifImage.animatedImage = [self.gifsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}); 
});

Comment: I don't have any exception. Maybe i have a smooth scroll because my gif always play?

Comment: Now i need to see your whole code for that particular class. Can you please post it on any open file sharing site and post a link for that?

Comment: I solve my problem to unable animation at the beginning and scrolling and start animation only for visible cell

Answer (score 0):

swift extension based on [Kampai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26401392/8351061):

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setGif(_ url: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
             do {
                let gifData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: url) ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = UIImage.sd_image(withGIFData: gifData)
                }
            } catch let error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = UIImage(named: "defaultImg")// set default image here
                }
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

use it as:

```
cell.imageGif.setGif("image url")
```