# displaying a lot of gifs in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, gif, giphy, giphy-api

In my app I want to show gifs from giphy. The fetching and everyting is no problem, but I don't know what's the best way to display for example all trending gifs. 
I have a collectionview which should display all gifs with this code:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: GifChooserCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GifChooserCell

      let data = try! Data(contentsOf: gif.giphyURL)
      let image = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: data)
      cell.image.animatedImage = image


    return cell
  }
```

The problem is that this loads everything into RAM and the application is extremely slow. What's the best way to do this? Async? Lazy loading?

Comment: I think you can take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26401392/2894160

Comment: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958313/8351061

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with AImage which also loads APNG files.  What I found was that all these Gif and APNG frameworks use separate CADisplayLinks for their firing.  In my case, CPU usage was about 7% per cell, and grew linearly with the # of cells.

When I disabled the CADisplayLinks objects, my CPU usage was about 3% total after loading.

For a solution, I'm considering stopping all animation once scrolling starts, or possibly using a singleton to drive all my APNG files.

Hope this helps.

---

UPDATE:

I went ahead and converted all my APNG files to MSSticker items by first saving the APNG files to disk, and then creating an array of stickers.

Using Stickers, my CPU usage is at 5% and memory is at 60MB for 7 APNG files.  My original method of using an AImageView to drive each APNG gets about 40% CPU usage.

Comment: please can you provide some example same thing i want it or suggestion .

Comment: @DhavalBhadania what I did was saved the APNG file to disk and then created the MSSticker like this: 'let sticker : MSSticker
                
                do
                {
                    try data.write(to: url)
                    sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: name)
                    
                    stickers.append(sticker)
                }
                catch
                {
                    print ("could not load sticker")
                }'